# misuse of aggregate: max() when getting the max of a view in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, sql-view

I have created a `VIEW (VISIT_VIEW)` that has two columns, citizens and `count(visitsDoctors) AS ToTal_Visits`:

```
CREATE VIEW VISIT_VIEW AS
SELECT citizen, COUNT(doctor) AS Total_Visits
FROM citizensvisits
GROUP BY citizen, doctor;
```

That returns a lis of how many times each citizen has visited a doctor

```
citizen1 1
citizen1 2
citizen1 5
...
citizen3 10
citizen3 4
```

Then I need to create a new view that will hold the MAX of the TotalVisits and for each citizen

```
CREATE VIEW MAXVISITS AS
SELECT citizens,  Total_Visits AS MaxTotal_Visits
FROM VISIT_VIEW
WHERE MaxTotal_Visits  =  max("Total_Visits")
GROUP BY citizens, MaxTotal_Visits;
```

so when trying to

```
SELECT *
FROM MAXVISIT_VIEW
```

I get

> Result: misuse of aggregate: max()

What am I doing wrong ?

edit: I ve put the `VISIT_VEW` code and to clarify, I need a new view that should list for each citizen's its MAX visits ie

```
citizen1 5
citizen3 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `MAX()` aggregate function directly.
You must aggregate again:

```
CREATE VIEW MAXVISITS AS
SELECT citizen, MAX(Total_Visits) AS MaxTotal_Visits
FROM VISIT_VIEW
GROUP BY citizen
```

or without the use of `VISIT_VIEW`, selecting directly from the table with `MAX()` window function:

```
CREATE VIEW MAXVISITS AS
SELECT DISTINCT citizen, 
       MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY citizen) AS Total_Visits 
FROM citizensvisits 
GROUP BY citizen, doctor;
```

Comment: Still, if I do a `SELECT * FROM MAXVISITS GROUP BY citizens, MaxTotal_Visits` I get back only one row, and not as many rows a citizens...

Comment: @Just_Newbie I do not propose to do: `"SELECT * FROM MAXVISITS GROUP BY citizens, MaxTotal_Visits"`. Do: `SELECT * FROM MAXVISITS`

Comment: yes, still the same even with `SELECT * FROM MAXVISITS`; only one row in the end...

Comment: @Just_Newbie then there is only 1 row with the max visits. Your view `VISIT_VIEW` returns 1 row for each value of `citizens`. So MAXVISITS returns the row(s) with the max value of those values. Isn't this that you want?

Comment: @Just_Newbie post the code of `VISIT_VIEW`.

Comment: Ah, sorry; no, I need to have the MAX visit for all citizens separately not the MAX from all, meaning that one row per citizen listing the max visits.I thought that the `GROUP BY citizens, MaxTotal_Visits` does that (I ve added on top of your answer, but still I get back only one row as I said.

Comment: @Just_Newbie This is why you must post the code of `VISIT_VIEW`. In your question you say that you have 1 row for each citizen with columns citizens and count(visitsDoctors). So if there is already 1 row for each citizens what max value do you want for each citizens?

Comment: ok, just edited the IP and added more info.

Comment: @Just_Newbie this is something different and simpler, because in VISIT_VIEW you also group by doctor. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I might be sorely mistaken, but I believe you would need to do a sub select

Something like this, but not exactly

```
CREATE VIEW MAXVISITS AS
SELECT citizens,  Total_Visits AS MaxTotal_Visits
FROM VISIT_VIEW
WHERE MaxTotal_Visits = (SELECT MAX(Total_Visits) FROM VISIT_VIEW)
GROUP BY citizens, MaxTotal_Visits;
```

There may or may not be other problems. with my solution included.

Comment: Please see my comment on the previous reply - the solution works, but in the end I never get all of the citizens

Comment: @Just_Newbie
Could I get a sample data set?